# I want to check if password and username contain at least one symbol?

Tags: python, ascii

I want this function to work in my is_password_good function.

```
def is_ascii(some_string) :
    for each_letter in some_string:
        if ord(each_letter) < 128:
        return False
    return True
```

The is_good_password function makes certain the user's password is at least 10 characters long and that at least one uppercase and lowercase exists.

How can I pass my ASCII function to check if the user creates a passwords using at least one symbol by ASCII standards?

```
def is_good_password(password):
    count_upper, count_lower = 0, 0
    for characters in password:
        if characters.isupper():
        count_upper += 1
        if characters.islower():
        count_lower += 1
    is_password_good = True
    if len(password) <= 10:
        print "Password is too weak, must be more than 10 characters long!"
    is_password_good = False
    if count_upper < 1 or count_lower < 1:
        print "Password must contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase character!"
        is_password_good = False
        create_user(database)
    print "Welcome! Username & Password successfully created!"
return is_password_good
```

Comment: Well, what you gave doesn't work because it returns false if *any* character *is* a letter (upper or lower), digit, *or* symbol. But to answer this we'd need to know what you consider a symbol "by ASCII standards". Any character that's not alpha or numeric?

Comment: @DavidRobinson want to check if the password contains at least one alpha numeric characters, ig. #, !, $, etc.

Comment: A character code above 127 is undefined by the ASCII standard. There are many character representations which use these character codes, but they are mutually incompatible. A user connecting from a loan computer would be locked out if they don't have the privileges to configure the character set and input method, or they might not know how. For the sake of your users, please reconsider this requirement.

Comment: @MartianE: `#, !, $` are *not* alpha numeric characters.

Comment: @DavidRobinson symbols**

Answer (score 4):

You can check `string.punctuation` exist in string or not.

```
>>>string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

def getmix(password):
    Upper=len(set(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',password)))
    Lower=len(set(re.findall(r'[a-z]',password)))
    Nums=len(set(re.findall(r'[0-9]',password)))
    Symb=len(set(re.findall(r'[~!@#$%^&\*()_+=-`]')))
    return (Upper, Lower, Nums, Symb)
```

Should give you a good starting point.

Comment: you could rename getmix to qualify, strip the `len` and then return `all(tuple)`, I think that would be a bit more elegant

Comment: Could do but I intended the OP to be able to customise the rules, e.g. at least 10 chars with at least 3 of 4 categories upper, lower, number and symbol - I also *personally* dislike password errors that don't tell me *why* my password failed.

Comment: It's all theoretical to me, I wouldn't roll my own, if it did, I would check for all lower case and 4 spaces separated by other characters: http://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 2):

The function `somestring.isalnum()` will return `False` if not all characters in the string are alphabetics or numbers.

The precise definition of these categories are locale-dependent; make sure you know which locale you are using.

By the by, ASCII is only defined up to character code 127. If you go above 127, you need to know which character set and encoding you are dealing with. However, characters like `#` and `!` are indeed defined in ASCII, and have character codes in the 30-something range. You are better off using library functions which abstract away the precise character codes, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
has_symbol = False
for c in '~!@#$%^&*()_+=-`':
    if c in password:
        has_symbol = True
        break
if not has_symbol:
    print "Password must contain at least one uppercase and one lowercase character!"
    is_password_good = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Always use the builtins, don't roll your own, so in that spirit, use the string module for a canonical list of symbols:

```
import string

symbols = string.punctuation
```

and printing `symbols` shows us these characters:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

You can pass to `any` the "one iterable in another" construction:

```
if any(char in symbols for char in some_string):
    print 'password good'
```

However, I actually prefer the set methods instead of the above construction:

```
if set(symbols).intersection(some_string):
    print 'password good'
```

but Triplee's advice on isalnum is just as potent, doesn't require importing the string module, and quite shorter.

```
if not some_string.isalnum():
    print 'password good'
```